# Analog of monitor which does not lead to freezes of the interface

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, monitoring

I have some heavy computation wrapped by `Monitor` and `ProgressIndicator`. It is the template:

```
Monitor[Table[
   SomeCode[list[[l]]], {l, 1, Length[list], 
    1}], Row[{ProgressIndicator[l, {1, Length[list]}], "i = ", l, 
    "/", Length[list], 
    " m = ", list[[l]]}, " "]];
```

Because of the reasons discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297624/why-does-mathematicas-interface-freeze-when-scrolling-to-the-evaluating-cell), the interface of the notebook freezes if scrolling to the evaluating cell; this is due to `Monitor`.

What can be an analog of `Monitor` which is free of this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally don't like any form of Monitor or ProgressIndicators in the  M f/e, because a) it can not be moved on the four screens, b) there is a lot of graphical and MathLink overhead involved (you may know the adage "graphics are expensive"), c) I usually prefer just a single number, like 78%, instead of graphics flickery, that may be my trader background---most traders don't like graphics flickery but key information in single, meaningsful numbers. So my suggestions to you:

1. See if my proposed solution on [How can I change the color of the bar in a ProgressIndicator?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20496/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-bar-in-a-progressindicator/20503#20503) works for you. You can move the progress bar window anywhere you want. To avoid freezes or other interaction problems you can now minimize the f/e window and just look at the progress bar window. Assuming it can run on its own and you don't need to check for errors during the execution of your big loop. Also works great in text/script/batch mode, i. e. you don't even have a M f/e. I never use the M f/e unless I know for sure I'll want to use a M f/e feature, and to call JLink you don't need the M f/e.
2. I use the totally underused status line in the lower-left corner of the M f/e to write progress information.

   sl[x___] :=
   LinkWrite[$ParentLink,
   SetNotebookStatusLine[EvaluationNotebook[],StringJoin @@ Map[ToString, {x}]]];

for example with something like

```
With[{length=17},
Do[Pause@1;
sl[ToString@i<>"/"<>ToString@length<>"="<>ToString[N[100 i/length]]<>"%"],    {i,length}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Andreas's answer is a good and nifty option, but this ressource function also does the job (in many practical cases, I guess):

[MonitorProgress - Monitor the progress of a computation and display the current step and estimated time remaining](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MonitorProgress)

Try, for instance, that one:

```
ResourceFunction["MonitorProgress"]@
 Map[Exponent[MinimalPolynomial[FunctionExpand[Cos[# Degree]], x], 
    x] &, Range[90]]
```

Comment: Sounds simple, I will check, thanks!